# OneHotEncoder - multiple columns at once

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a dataset (200, 600) where 180 - 199 are strings, that I need to convert.
I am using OneHotEncoder, but I am stuck on how to convert all string columns at once.

```
ohe = OneHotEncoder()

aa = np.array( X[:,199]).reshape(-1, 1)

one_hot_encoder = ohe.fit(aa)
ohe_coded = ohe.transform(aa).toarray()
```

This is what I have for now. I can convert one column with **X[:,199]**, but I have no idea how to convert multiple at once, or if it is even possible in some simple way.

Comment: Is `ohe.fit_transform(X[:,180:199])` not working?

Comment: @FlaviaGiammarino Thank you! I just couldn't find right syntax for selecting multiple columns at once, so I thought it was impossile.

Comment: Just to propose a minor change to the @FlaviaGiammarino's comment, you probably need to use `ohe.fit_transform(X[:,180:200])` in order to pick the right slice